# Downloading and Installing fonts using powershell commands only

Tags: windows, powershell, fonts, windows-11

Im making a powershell script to install and initialize oh-my-posh on a windows 11 terminal. The problem im having is oh-my-posh requires a font called `CaskaydiaCove Nerd Font` (or other nerd font) from [this website](https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads)

Is there anyway i can download and install the font needed only using powershell? You might say that why not just include the font files with the script, but that wont be always the updated version. The goal is when the script executes it will install the latest `CaskaydiaCove Nerd Font`

If there were only a repository where i can simply get the latest version of these fonts

UPDATE:

So i was able to make lines of commands that is working but it needs polishing.

```
winget install -e --id Git.Git
git clone -–depth 1 https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts.git
cd nerd-fonts
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned # Changes Restricted -> RemoteSigned
Y  # needs manual input
./install.ps1 CascadiaCode -WindowsCompatibleOnly
```

So it basically installs git, downloads the latest repository only, and install.

How do you change execution policy without me requiring to input the 'Y'? Also do i need to change back the execution policy after installing?

Also there is a problem after doing `winget install -e --id Git.Git` git is not recognized and requires a restart of the powershell , is there anyway i can mitigate this?

Comment: Maybe this might help: https://adictoalaintensidad.blogspot.com/2021/11/configuracion-de-powershell-en-windows.html

Comment: @MarkusMeyer it will not download the latest version of the font though, for example the one liner it gave is is for v 2.1 the latest currently is 2.3. Im exploring the git method also where the script will first install git, download the repo, and follow steps [here](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts#option-3-install-script). Im currently frankensteining codes right now to make it work.

Comment: You can use "Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned -force" to suppress the conformation prompt. This can be found on Microsoft's website:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy

Comment: @Shifty Am i right if i use `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process -force` ? I added scope to be limited that instance only.

Comment: @DrakeJest
Yes, that will only affect the current Powershell instance., if that is what you mean.

Comment: @Shifty yes, i do not want to permanently change settings , and want to keep any changes to that instance of the script. All that remains now is how to refresh the powershell without closing, if i dont restart the powershell after git installation (assuming git was not previously installed) it will not recognize git commands

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the process described at the [link](https://adictoalaintensidad.blogspot.com/2021/11/configuracion-de-powershell-en-windows.html) provided in the [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1765024/downloading-and-installing-fonts-using-powershell-commands-only#comment2745950_1765024) by [@Markus Meyer](https://superuser.com/users/1125377/markus-meyer), but easier to manage and accounting for the latest version of the font release.

### Download and Install Latest Nerd-Font Release

The code is a PowerShell script that downloads and installs a font named "CascadiaCode" from the Nerd Fonts GitHub repository.

The script starts by setting the font name and the URI of the Nerd Fonts repository. It then sends a web request to the latest release URI of the repository, which causes a redirect to the URL containing the actual version number of the latest release tag.

To capture the URL of the redirect, the script instructs `Invoke-WebRequest` to not allow the redirect to occur by using `-MaximumRedirection 0`, but to capture the response and look at the value of the *Location* header for the URL.

The last part of the URL contains the version, so `Split-Path` is used with the *-Leaf* switch parameter to extract the latest version number from the response header.

Next, the script downloads the font archive and extracts it to a folder with the same name as the font. It then uses the Windows Shell COM object to copy all the font files with the ".ttf" extension to the Windows Fonts folder.

```
$FontName = 'CascadiaCode'
$NerdFontsURI = 'https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/releases'

$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$NerdFontsURI/latest" -MaximumRedirection 0 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$LatestVersion = Split-Path -Path $WebResponse.Headers['Location'] -Leaf

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$NerdFontsURI/download/$LatestVersion/$FontName.zip" -OutFile "$FontName.zip"

Expand-Archive -Path "$FontName.zip"

$ShellApplication = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
$Fonts = $ShellApplication.NameSpace(0x14)

Get-ChildItem -Path ".\$FontName" -Include '*.ttf' -Recurse | ForEach-Object -Process {
    $Fonts.CopyHere($_.FullName)
}
```